# my code is messy and wasteful of lines, how do I make my code simple

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

can this script be made simpler? I'm just learning about javascript, so I don't really know which syntax to use.

My HTML
I have several **id** consisting of **"doc1, doc2, doc3, .."** and there is another **id** **"icon-cek1, icon-ceck2, icon-cek3"**. **"icon-cek"** is used to display the place of a checkmark icon when the upload is successful / according to the extension that has been specified and if the file fails / doesn't match the extension will display a crossmark.

```
<label> DOcument 1</label>
<input type="file"id="doc1"/>
<label> Choose</label>
<div id="icon-cek1"></div>

<label> DOcument 2</label>
<input type="file"id="doc2" />
<label> Choose</label>
<div  id="icon-cek2"></div>

<label> DOcument 3</label>
<input type="file"id="doc3"/>
<label> Choose</label>
<div id="icon-cek3"></div>


    $.fn.checkFileType = function (options) {
    var defaults = {
      allowedExtensions: [],
      success: function () {},
      error: function () {},
    };
    options = $.extend(defaults, options);

    return this.each(function () {
      $(this).on("change", function () {
        var value = $(this).val(),
          file = value.toLowerCase(),
          extension = file.substring(file.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);

        if ($.inArray(extension, options.allowedExtensions) == -1) {
          options.error();
          $(this).focus();
        } else {
          options.success();
        }
      });
    });
  };

  $("#doc1").checkFileType({
    allowedExtensions: ["pdf"],
    success: function () {
      document.getElementById("icon-cek1").className = "checkmark";
    },
    error: function () {
      document.getElementById('doc1').value='';
      document.getElementById("icon-cek1").className = "crossmark";
    },
  });

    $("#doc2").checkFileType({
    allowedExtensions: ["pdf"],
    success: function () {
      document.getElementById("icon-cek2").className = "checkmark";
    },
    error: function () {
      document.getElementById("doc2").value = "";
      document.getElementById("icon-cek2").className = "crossmark";
    },
  });

  $("#doc3").checkFileType({
    allowedExtensions: ["pdf"],
    success: function () {
      document.getElementById("icon-cek3").className = "checkmark";
    },
    error: function () {
    alert("Just PDF");
      document.getElementById("doc3").value = "";
      document.getElementById("icon-cek3").className = "crossmark";
    },
  });
```

Comment: codereview.stackexchange.com for working code that needs improvement. ;)

Comment: This code is not functional code. Please start with code that will actually operate.